# Turn a List of Str into a List of Int (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I need to turn a list of strings into a list of integers. I've searched for this question but I don't think people have had the same problem I've had.

Lets say I have a list of strings:
List1 = ['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10', '11 12 13 14 15']

How would I turn that into:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] ?

I'm confused how to do this because instead of ['1', '2', '3' etc...] there are about 5 numbers in one string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, join each element of `List1` to form a single, space-separated string. Then split that and convert each element of the resulting list to an integer.

```
>>> List1 = ['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10', '11 12 13 14 15']
>>> [ int(x) for x in ' '.join(List1).split()]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

You can also use a nested `for` with the list comprehension:

```
>>> [ int(x) for y in List1 for x in y.split() ]
```

You parse each `for` expression in the same order as a regular nested `for` loop.

Comment: `[ int(x) for x in ' '.join(List1).split() ]` # <- needs to be a `]`